# How to search a tuple and increment while saving the results

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

-- Sample test data
type Movies = (String, String)

sample :: [Movies]
sample = [("I am legend","Will Smith"),
        ("Rise of the Planet of the Apes","James Franco"),
        ("Godzilla","Bryan Cranston")]

sellTicket :: [Movies] -> String -> String -> [Movies]
sellTicket [] _ _ = []
sellTicket ((title, actor): xs) aTitle anActor
    | title == aTitle && actor == anActor = 
        (title, actor):sellTicket xs aTitle anActor
    | otherwise = (title,actor):sellTicket xs aTitle anActor
```

Thanks guys for all the help, its all working fine now.

And James Franko was in rise of the planet of the apes.

Comment: here's a hint: what line of `sellTicket` currently handles the case where the list doesn't contain a match.  Also, James Franco was in Rise of the Planet of the Apes, not Planet of the Apes.

Comment: ``sample`` is immutable in Haskell, which means that it will always be as you defined it. (It cannot change state)

Comment: Once you have bound `sample` its value wont change. You probably want to either pass around the modified `sample` or use a monad to keep track of the state.

Comment: Also, what should ``[Sales]`` be?

Comment: @user3849712 That case would only occur when you've exhaustively searched your whole list of `Movie`s.  So maybe you should think about adding the new element then: `sellTicket [] aTitle anActor = ???`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
sellTicket :: [Movies] -> String -> String -> [Movies]
sellTicket l title actor = sellTicketHelp l title actor False
  where      
    sellTicketHelp [] _ _ True = []
    sellTicketHelp [] title actor False = [(title, actor, 1)]
    sellTicketHelp ((t, a, q):xs) title actor b
        | title == t && actor == a = (t, a, q+1) : sellTicketHelp xs title actor True
        | otherwise = (t, a, q) : sellTicketHelp xs title actor b
```

`sellTicket` now has an auxiliary function which in addition to the other parameters takes a boolean value which determines if a match has already been found or not. If the list has been traversed and a match has been found it does returns am empty list on which the rest will get consed. Otherwise if it has not yet found a match it returns a list containing the new movie with a quantity of 1 on which everything will get consed back.